# jQuery selectors not living in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

Till Chrome 22.0, when I put in my javascript code

```
console.debug($('.page'));
```

it used to return to my Google Chrome console:

```
<div class="page"></div>
```

which was *living* DOM object. I could easily find the object on my page by hover it.
Yesterday I've updated my Chrome browser to version 23.0 and now the same js code returns something like

```
[<div>, selector: ".page", context: #document]
```

which is raw js object. I can expand it and read it's attributes, but there is no *living* DOM object possible to see on page.

I've tried to replace  `console.debug` with  `console.log` or add  `$('.page').get()` to jQuery selector, but without success.

What's also interesting when I write  `console.debug($('.page'));` directly into Chrome console it appears like in Chrome 22.0. Problem occurs only while debugging from js code.

Comment: Try `console.log($('.page')[0])` It works for me @ 23.0.1271.64

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works but of course returns only first of matched elements. Earlier I could get array of _living_ objects.

Comment: if you type the selector into chromes developer console it should display all elements as it did in earlier versions.
i haven't found another way to output an array of elements yet.

Comment: +1, this is a killer for quickly debugging jQuery.

Comment: I upmodded @supernova but note this is only a workaround not a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, this could work to strip out the jQuery properties from the DOM array:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call($('.page')));
```

BUT, when consoling an array of DOM nodes, the dev toolbar will no longer let you browse the DOM nodes from within the array (except the native properties). The only way I know to get around this is to log each node individually:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call($('.page')).forEach(function(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
});
```

Or simply:

```
$('.page').each(function(i, elem) {
    console.log(elem);
});
```

Comment: Using this idea, could do something like `console.logDOM = function(x){$(x).each(function(i, elem) {
    console.log(elem);
});};` to add a logging method that works the way the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime to debug i test also the ".html()" or innerHtml to debug some on-fly html code but "David" way is also what i did.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be fixed in version 23.0.1271.91.

Comment: I am using 23.0.1271.91 and still see the behavior.

Comment: @nailer Weird. F12 -> `$('#content')` on this page works fine for me. About says `Version 23.0.1271.91 m`

Comment: I am running Version 23.0.1271.95 and I when I type $('#content') on this page I get [> <div id="content">...</div>] instead of the expected <div id="content">...</div>.